WPF MVVM UI won't update after initializing
I have a xaml script that will not listen to OnPropertyChanged. when initialising the view, it functions correctly, but i cant update it.
Parts.xaml:
<UserControl x:Class="Page_Navigation_App.View.Parts"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Page_Navigation_App.ViewModel"
             xmlns:utils="clr-namespace:Page_Navigation_App.Utilities"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="600"
             d:DesignWidth="622"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             Style="{StaticResource Page_Style}">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:PartsVM x:Name="_model"/>
    </UserControl.DataContext> 
    .....
    <Grid Margin="15">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
        <!-- Width for the splitter -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <!-- Width of the details pane -->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- ListView for Parts or Variants -->
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TableData}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPart, Mode=TwoWay}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Margin="0,0,0,10"
          Visibility="{Binding PartsVisibility}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Card Container -->
                <Border Background="#343a40"
                    CornerRadius="10"
                    Padding="10"
                    BorderBrush="#3C3F41"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Margin="5"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    Width="Auto"
                    >

                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <!-- Define rows for labels, values, and button -->
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!-- ID Field -->
                        <TextBlock Text="Image:"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               Foreground="White"
                               Margin="0,0,10,0"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding [ID], UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}"
                               Foreground="White"
                               Margin="0,0,20,0"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <!-- Description Field -->
                        <TextBlock Text="Description:"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               Foreground="White"
                               Margin="0,0,10,0"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding [Description],UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                               Foreground="White"
                               Margin="0,0,20,0"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <!-- Additional Details (Optional) -->
                        <TextBlock Text="Type:"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               Foreground="White"
                               Margin="0,0,10,0"
                               Grid.Column="2"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Visibility="{Binding [Type], Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibilityConverter} }"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding [Type] , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                               Foreground="White"
                               Margin="0,0,20,0"
                               Grid.Column="2"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Visibility="{Binding [Type], Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibilityConverter}}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <Button Content="Variants"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowVariantsCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}  , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                            Grid.Column="3"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.RowSpan="3"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Margin="0,10,0,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Padding="5,2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>


Parts.xaml.cs:

namespace Page_Navigation_App.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Customers.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Parts : UserControl
    {
        //private PartsVM _model = new PartsVM();
        public Parts()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //DataContext = new PartsVM(); 
        }


    }
}


PartsVM.cs:
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Page_Navigation_App.Utilities;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Page_Navigation_App.ViewModel
{
    class PartsVM : Utilities.ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly DBHandler _dbHandler;

        private static string TCPServer = "*****";
        private static string DBCatalog = "*****";

        private string _test;
        //private DBHandler dbHandler;
        private SqlConnection _sqlConnection;

        private ObservableCollection<DataRow> _tableData;
        private DataRow _selectedPart;
        private ObservableCollection<Variant> _variants;
        private bool _isViewingVariants;
        private Visibility _partsVisibility;
        private Visibility _reversePartsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        private ObservableCollection<EndUser> _endUsers;

        private string tableName = "Sales.Parts";


        // Define column names at the class level
        private readonly ObservableCollection<string> columnNames = new ObservableCollection<string> { "ID", "Description", "Type", "Comment" };

        int i = 0;



        public ObservableCollection<EndUser> EndUsers
        {
            get { return _endUsers; }
            set
            {
                _endUsers = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EndUsers));
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<DataRow> TableData
        {
            get { return _tableData; }
            set { _tableData = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TableData)); }

        }
        public string Test
        {
            get { return _test; }
            set { _test = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Test)); }

        }

        public DataRow SelectedPart
        {
            get { return _selectedPart; }
            set { _selectedPart = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Variant> Variants
        {
            get { return _variants; }
            set { _variants = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public bool IsViewingVariants
        {
            get { return _isViewingVariants; }
            set { _isViewingVariants = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public Visibility PartsVisibility
        {
            get { return _partsVisibility; }
            set { _partsVisibility = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public Visibility ReversePartsVisibility
        {
            get { return _reversePartsVisibility; }
            set { _reversePartsVisibility = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public ICommand ShowVariantsCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand BackToPartsCommand { get; set; }
        public PartsVM()
        {
            _tableData = new ObservableCollection<DataRow>();


            SQLConnectionManager.Initialize();
            _sqlConnection = SQLConnectionManager.GetConnection();

            if (_sqlConnection == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Database connection is not initialized.");
            }
            _dbHandler = new DBHandler(_sqlConnection);
            
            GetAll();
            //Search("test");
        }

        public void GetAll()
        {
            i++;
            string query = $"SELECT * FROM {tableName};";
            var dataTable = new DataTable();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, _sqlConnection))
            {
                using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    // Fill the DataTable with the result of the query
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }
            }
            this.Test = i.ToString();
            // Convert DataTable rows to ObservableCollection<DataRow>
            var rows = new ObservableCollection<DataRow>(dataTable.AsEnumerable());

            // Clear the existing TableData and add the new rows
            TableData.Clear();
            /*foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                TableData.Add(row);
            }*/
            TableData = rows;

            // Notify that TableData has changed
            //OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TableData));
            

           



        }
        public void Search(string searchTerm)
        {
            // Escape special characters in searchTerm for SQL LIKE
            string escapedSearchTerm = "%" + searchTerm + "%";

            // Generate the LIKE clause for each column
            string likeClause = string.Join(" OR ", columnNames.Select(col => $"{col} LIKE @searchTerm"));
            string query = $"SELECT * FROM {tableName} WHERE {likeClause};";
            //MessageBox.Show(query);

            var dataTable = new DataTable();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, _sqlConnection))
            {
                // Add the parameter once to be used in all LIKE statements
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchTerm", escapedSearchTerm);

                using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    // Fill the dataTable with the query result
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }
            }
            var rows = new ObservableCollection<DataRow>(dataTable.AsEnumerable());
            int test = TableData.Count;
            // Convert DataTable rows to an ObservableCollection of DataRow
            TableData.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow row in rows)
            {
                TableData.Add(row);
            }
            TableData = rows;
                       
          
        }

    }
}


ViewmodelBase:
namespace Page_Navigation_App.Utilities
{
    class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}


I know the functions are triggered, as i have debugged it.
The search function is triggered by a function in a different script. I also know that the DataTable is being updated correctly, but the UI will not update. I have tried to trigger the PropertyChanged manualy, with and without setting UpdateSourceTrigger explicitly.
I have no idea why this does not work. Thanks in advance


<TextBlock Text="{Binding [ID], UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}"

You are using invalid syntax, the correct binding syntax here would be:
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />

However the real problem is that you're trying to bind to a DataRow which doesn't expose properties. You need to create objects out of those rows that expose the properties you're trying to bind to.

Also to be clear, nothing you wrote there "functions correctly". That is very low quality, incorrect code.

{Binding [ID]} or {Binding Path=[ID]} is valid syntax and works because DataRow has this indexer property. There is however no change notification.
